# timing belt pulleys

Tags: vw, jetta, timing-belt

On my 2001 Jetta GLS 2.0 SOHC im replacing all pulleys for timing belt and i was wondering how to know the correct position to put new ones on. I will also be putting new belt. i know there are marking on them at least mine there are but how do i know i put them in the correct position to start with. I have been told just taker to place to have put on but i want to learn for my self. i cant find any marking on block.

Comment: Which exact pulleys are you talking about? Timing or serpentine belt? [Does this video help you?](https://youtu.be/L_5aXPkkkts)

Comment: the timing belt and replacing all pulleys.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have your manual to hand, but the manufacturers use one of two systems normally to show timing : marks that you have been looking for or they use holes in the pulley webs and matching holes in the cylinder head or block which locate the positions precisely. Once locked into position then you slide the belt on and release the tensioner. then check the positions are correct after rotating the engine by hand...

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't suffered a belt slippage incident, you look at the camshaft sprocket. You should see a notch in the sprocket and an arrow behind it. As long as the two line up properly, you shouldn't have an issue. Ensure you line it up **BEFORE YOU TAKE THE BELT OFF!!!** Should look like this:

[image]

If you've already taken the belt off, you'll need to ensure the engine is at Top Dead Center (TDC) on cylinder 1, and then camshaft sprocket in the position indicated.